# SQLite: truncation using mathematical operators on integer value

Tags: sqlite

I had a strange behaviour trying to do some easy calculations on a Select working with **SQLite3**.
Probably it's my approach that was wrong, because maybe it would be better to avoid calculations on sqlite. So to avoid these kind of problems I moved mathematical operations on the javascript code (it's a Titanium app).

By the way I knew that sqlite before doing calculations usually "converts" data to Numeric type, as written here:
http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#operators

> "All mathematical operators (+, -, *, /, %, <<, >>, &, and |) cast
>   both operands to the NUMERIC storage class prior to being carried out"

In my case when the SUM(value) returned a integer the following /100 truncated the value removing all the decimal numbers, while with a SUM(value) numeric, the following /100 worked as expected.

[image]

Anyone could explain me what happened here and why? I cannot understand if I did a mistake or if it's a bug in sqlite (quite absurd).

Comment: What happened? Integer division. Also see [sum(X), total(X)](https://sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#sumunc)

Comment: In the first row SUM(taxable) = 171, but SUM(taxable)/100 = 1, I expected 1.71. In second row everything worked well. Ok that SUM(...) return a Integer if every value is a Integer, but in theory the division should transform it in Numeric. For me this behaviour is very strange, I don't know. By the way thank you for answering.

Comment: *"I expected 1.71"* That's how paper-and-pencil division works, but that's not how *integer division* works. You might want to use the nonstandard aggregate function `total(X)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NUMERIC means either INTEGER or REAL. Your original values already are numbers, so a cast to NUMERIC does not change anything.

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#sumunc) says:

> The result of sum() is an integer value if all non-NULL inputs are integers. If any input to sum() is neither an integer or a NULL then sum() returns a floating point value which might be an approximation to the true sum.

If all the value in the group are integers, then `sum()` returns an integer, and the division is an integer division.

If you cannot ensure that all table values are REALs, then you have to force the division to be done in floating point by casting the result to REAL, or just dividing by `100.0`.

Comment: I understood that the SUM of only integer returned a integer but I missed that the / on two integers returned the result of a integer division, because I understood that the conversion was automatic... so it's enough to divide by 100.0. Thank you very much, I tried and actually it works.